# Ruby - Nokogiri - Need to put node.value to an array

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

What I'm trying to do is read the value for all the nodes in this XML and put them into an array.  This should be simple but for some reason it's driving me nuts.

XML

```
<ArrayOfAddress>
<Address>
<AddressId>297424fe-cfff-4ee1-8faa-162971d2645f</AddressId>
<FirstName>George</FirstName>
<LastName>Washington</LastName>
<Address1>123 Main St</Address1>
<Address2>Apt #611</Address2>
<City>New York</City>
<State>NY</State>
<PostalCode>10110</PostalCode>
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
<EmailAddress>test@test.com</EmailAddress>
<PhoneNumber>5555551234</PhoneNumber>
<AddressType>CustomerAddress</AddressType>
</Address>
</ArrayOfAddress>
```

Code

```
class MassageRepsone
def parse_resp
    @@get_address.url_builder #URL passed through HTTPClient - @@resp is the xml above
      doc = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(@@resp)
      @@values = doc.each do |node|
         node.value
    end
end

    @@get_address.parse_resp
    obj = [@@values] 
    Array(obj)
    p obj
end
```

The code snippet from above returns the following:

```
297424fe-cfff-4ee1-8faa-162971d2645f


George


Washington


123 Main St


Apt #622


New York


NY


10110


US


test.test.com


5555551234


CustomerAddress
```

I tried putting @@values to a string and applying chomp but that just prints the newlines as nil and puts quotes around the values.  Not sure what the next step is or if I need to approach this differently with Nokogiri.

Comment: fix the formatting of your code please.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you don't understand Nokogiri, but you also don't understand what Ruby will do with `each` either, or understand how to create a collection using `each`. Also, knowing why you'd want to use `each` vs. `map` would help your code. Also, you need to understand when to use `@@` vs. `@` vs. creating an local variable.

Comment: Yup I'm learning as I go.  The reason for the @@ vs. @ vs. local variables is because I'm creating class variables and instance variables that are used between classes in various files.  I'm refining as I go and appreciate all your help Tin Man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that this code...

```
@@values = doc.each do |node|
  node.value
end
```

...calls `node.value` on each node, but then doesn't *do* anything with the result. `Array#each` returns the array that was iterated, and that's what you are setting `@@values` to. But `doc.each` doesn't have all the nodes in the document.

Perhaps you want:

```
# Find all text nodes and extract them individually
@values = doc.xpath('//text()').map{ |node| node.text }
```

It's hard to be sure because you don't explain what the array ought to look like in the end. Perhaps you want:

```
@addresses = doc.css('Address').map do |address|
  address.xpath( './/text()' ).map{ |node| node.text }
end
```

...which would give you an array of one array for each `<Address>` element, filled with the values in that element.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz the first of the two solutions works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I'd do what it seems you're asking:

```
require 'ap'
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<XML
<ArrayOfAddress>
<Address>
<AddressId>297424fe-cfff-4ee1-8faa-162971d2645f</AddressId>
<FirstName>George</FirstName>
<LastName>Washington</LastName>
<Address1>123 Main St</Address1>
<Address2>Apt #611</Address2>
<City>New York</City>
<State>NY</State>
<PostalCode>10110</PostalCode>
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
<EmailAddress>test@test.com</EmailAddress>
<PhoneNumber>5555551234</PhoneNumber>
<AddressType>CustomerAddress</AddressType>
</Address>
</ArrayOfAddress>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
node_values = doc.search('//Address/*').map do |n|
  n.text
end

ap node_values
```

Which outputs:

```
[
    [ 0] "297424fe-cfff-4ee1-8faa-162971d2645f",
    [ 1] "George",
    [ 2] "Washington",
    [ 3] "123 Main St",
    [ 4] "Apt #611",
    [ 5] "New York",
    [ 6] "NY",
    [ 7] "10110",
    [ 8] "US",
    [ 9] "test@test.com",
    [10] "5555551234",
    [11] "CustomerAddress"
]
```

If you have multiple `Address` nodes then you'll need to tweak the code a little bit, based on how you want to process things, but it's not hard.

Comment: Awesome, that's tight.  Do you recommend any sites or reading material on using Nokogiri?  The site itself is useful but I'd love additional resources for really getting the hang of it.

Comment: Your very best source is the [Nokogiri-talk mail-list](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk). The developers monitor it and are very helpful. StackOverflow is an OK resource, but you'll find a lot of bad answers searching for related questions.

Comment: And, heh, any "tight"ness is thanks to Ruby. It's a very nice language, especially when coupled with libraries that are written by people who "grok" it. Nokogiri's developers do. You'll find Ruby's elegance starts to shine more and more as you get used to it and begin thinking in "the Ruby way".